# how to use a span tag for form fields in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my form, I used the span tag like the following:

```
<%= content_tag :span, f.object.User, class: 'username' %>
```

It looks like the following in HTML after i selected the value:

```
<span class="user" style="">Antony</span>
```

The problem is id doesn't get the value to the database when we create a form. I don't know the exact problem is. I want to use this content tag instead of text_field to get the value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you submit an HTML form, the only values that get POSTed are those that are in input fields such as text fields, selects, checkboxes, buttons, etc.  Content that is simply on the page -- in a span or not -- will not get posted back to the server.  That isn't a Rails issue, it's just the way HTML works.

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here, but a common approach when you want to display a value (not in an input box) and also post the value back with the form, is to both render the value on the page (in a span or however you want) and also add a hidden input field (`hidden_field_tag`) that also has the value in it.

Comment: yeah.. Thank you.. That makes sense.. Thank you Jacob. This is my first question in the stack overflow and get solved in 5 mints. Great. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, Jacob is correct. Better create a hidden field

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user, class: 'user' %>
<%= content_tag :span, f.object.User, class: 'username' %>
```

The first line get the value in it. I hope, Jacob answer would help you. :)